# Xcode 6.2 debugger detaches from device on app crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Xcode 6.2's debugger doesn't seem to be catching a crash from my application. Whenever it crashes, I just get a popup that says:

> Restore the connection to "Agile Lab's iPhone 6 Plus" and run "Tag
>   Beta" again, or if "Tag Beta" is still running, you can attach to it
>   by selecting Debug > Attach to Process > Tag Beta.

I have breakpoints on and a breakpoint for "All Exceptions." When I go to Window > Devices and hit "View Device Logs" it shows this:

```
Hardware Model:      iPhone7,1
OS Version:          iPhone OS 8.1.3 (12B466)
Kernel Version:      Darwin Kernel Version 14.0.0: Mon Jan 12 21:30:05 PST 2015; root:xnu-2783.3.26~3/RELEASE_ARM64_T7000
Date:                2015-03-31 15:12:15 -0400
Time since snapshot: 1230 ms

Free pages:                              2404
Active pages:                            40050
Inactive pages:                          18785
Speculative pages:                       1206
Throttled pages:                         0
Purgeable pages:                         524
Wired pages:                             147884
File-backed pages:                       11282
Anonymous pages:                         48760
Compressions:                            487127
Decompressions:                          189679
Compressor Size:                         40449
Uncompressed Pages in Compressor:        103077
Page Size:                               16384
Largest process:   Tag Beta

Processes
   Name       |            <UUID>                |     CPU Time|     rpages|       purgeable| recent_max| lifetime_max| fds |  [reason]         | (state)

WirelessRadioMan <REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>                     0.036         295                0           -           889   50   [vm-pageshortage]   (daemon) (idle)
 nsurlstoraged <REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>                     0.072         294                0           -           680   50   [vm-pageshortage]   (daemon) (idle)
          seld <REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>                     0.052         218                0           -           995   50   [vm-pageshortage]   (daemon)
 nsurlsessiond <REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>                     0.285         389                0           -          1326   50   [vm-pageshortage]   (daemon)
         passd <REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>                     0.211         623                0           -          2400   50   [vm-pageshortage]   (daemon)
          nfcd <REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>                     0.024         192                0           -           634   50   [vm-pageshortage]   (daemon)
 biometrickitd <REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>                     0.084         232                0           -           720   50   [vm-pageshortage]   (daemon)
   debugserver <REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>                     1.059         212                0           -           703   50   [vm-pageshortage]   (daemon)
    MobileMail <REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>                     0.471        1277                0           -          3744   50   [vm-pageshortage]   (resume) (continuous)
           lsd <REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>                     0.612         361                0           -          1136   50   [vm-pageshortage]   (daemon)
          tccd <REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>                     0.146         281                0           -           968   50                       (daemon)
      Tag Beta <REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>                    19.967       97247              524           -         55588  100                       (frontmost) (resume)
          ptpd <REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>                     1.226         786                0           -          2356   50                       (daemon)
      BTServer <REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>                     0.303         483                0           -          1811   50                       (daemon)
         wifid <REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>                     2.303         544                0           -          1786   50                       (daemon)
     lockdownd <REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>                     1.481         279                0           -          1007   50                       (daemon)
     locationd <REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>                    35.207        2182                0           -          5074   50                       (daemon)
    discoveryd <REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>                     4.462         580                0           -          1232  100                       (daemon)
  mediaserverd <REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>                    28.952       36002                0           -          5968   50                       (daemon)
       imagent <REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>                     0.418         522                0           -          1531   50                       (daemon)
 iaptransportd <REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>                     0.333         308                0           -           906   50                       (daemon)
identityservices <REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>                     1.016         724                0           -          2027   50                       (daemon)
      cfprefsd <REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>                     1.371         400                0           -           798   50                       (daemon)
       syslogd <REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>                     1.376         233                0           -           449   50                       (daemon)
        powerd <REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>                     0.608         215                0           -           514   50                       (daemon)
          apsd <REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>                     1.141         733                0           -          2076   50                       (daemon)
      networkd <REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>                     1.341         650                0           -          1747   50                       (daemon)
           vmd <REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>                     0.086         550                0           -          2441   50                       (daemon)
   dataaccessd <REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>                     0.571         853                0           -          2657   50                       (daemon)
      sharingd <REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>                     0.360         719                0           -          2260   50                       (daemon)
       searchd <REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>                     0.402         874                0           -          2886   50                       (daemon)
  syslog_relay <REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>                     0.246         113                0           -           237   50                       (daemon)
          geod <REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>                     1.152         868                0           -          1847   50                       (daemon)
   SpringBoard <REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>                    14.007        6886                0           -         28595   50                      
    backboardd <REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>                    63.774       13669              524           -          3673   50                       (daemon)
UserEventAgent <REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>                    17.578         916                0           -          2959  100                       (daemon)
     fseventsd <REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>                     0.689         387                0           -           629   50                       (daemon)
       configd <REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>                     0.729         530                0           -          1544   50                       (daemon)
  fairplayd.H2 <REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>                     0.530         149                0           -          1052   50                       (daemon)
    assertiond <REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>                     0.319         296                0           -          1012   50                       (daemon)
     distnoted <REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>                     0.078         186                0           -           321   50                       (daemon)
 wirelessproxd <REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>                     0.068         248                0           -          1065   50                       (daemon)
    aggregated <REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>                    23.356        1192                0           -          2375   50                       (daemon)
discoveryd_helpe <REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>                     0.020         153                0           -           752   50                       (daemon)
filecoordination <REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>                     0.030         224                0           -           898   50                       (daemon)
    DTMobileIS <REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>                     3.415         642                0         +25          2345   50                       (daemon)
     gputoolsd <REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>                     0.285         948                0           -          2340   50                       (daemon)
    CommCenter <REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>                    30.132        1626                0           -          5021   50                       (daemon)
       notifyd <REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>                     2.168         347                0           -           413   50                       (daemon)
   ReportCrash <REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY>                     0.043         162                0           -           579   50                       (daemon)

**End**
```

Now if I run the app in production mode, and attach Fabric, it does catch the exception properly:

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
-[TAGFeedJourneyTableViewCell previewImageView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14271e9d0

Thread : Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x000000018349a59c __exceptionPreprocess + 132
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x0000000193bec0e4 objc_exception_throw + 60
2  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001834a1664 __methodDescriptionForSelector
3  CoreFoundation                 0x000000018349e418 ___forwarding___ + 928
4  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001833a2b6c _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
5  Tag Beta                       0x000000010012ca3c -[TAGFeedViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] (TAGFeedViewController.m:603)
6  UIKit                          0x0000000187d71390 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1280
7  UIKit                          0x0000000187e2ecdc -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 276
8  UIKit                          0x0000000187ccb564 _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 356
9  UIKit                          0x0000000187c3ce78 _afterCACommitHandler + 532
10 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000183452a50 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
11 CoreFoundation                 0x000000018344f9dc __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 360
12 CoreFoundation                 0x000000018344fdbc __CFRunLoopRun + 836
13 CoreFoundation                 0x000000018337d0a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
14 GraphicsServices               0x000000018c5175a4 GSEventRunModal + 168
15 UIKit                          0x0000000187caeaa4 UIApplicationMain + 1488
16 Tag Beta                       0x0000000100123f7c main (main.m:14)
17 libdyld.dylib                  0x000000019425aa08 start + 4
```

While it's nice that Fabric is able to catch the issue, It'd be much more helpful if the debugger would catch the exception, so I could see values, stack traces, etc. Is there some setting that I just don't have on or is this an issue with Xcode?